# Architecture guidance for AWS run Rails app (Web/Worker setup)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are hosting application on AWS and are using EB (ElasticBeanstalk) for deployments. Application is Rails and we are using Sidekiq for background processes. We have decoupled RDS instance, ElasticCache (for Sidekiq communication) and generally, we are stateless architecture.

At the moment our web process and sidekiq process are running on same EC2 instances. This means that we need to use larger instances to support this process. We want to move to separate web and worker architecture. Idea is to move web processes on EC2 small instances and have one EC2 large instance dedicated to Sidekiq only.  Reason for this is that we have CPU usage issues where bigger worker jobs hog all the resources and take the instance down which than dominos in new instances and general not the optimal use of our resources.

This seems like no brainer to us, but we are having trouble finding web resources where this has been implemented. Also, it is confusing to us setting up Web EB app and Worker EB app separately. How would deploy work, would we deploy two separate EB applications at the same time? That does not seem safe.

We are looking on guidance on how to best go ahead achieving above goal, are there examples or setups that you could share where we could see a real-world example of this?

Also is a there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The web/worker setup you described for a Rails application is absolutely appropriate.  Within the same application, you can create an environment for your web server and an environment for your worker. Your code base can be deployed to both environments either separately (if your changes only affect either the worker or the web server), or at the same time (if your changes affect both environments). You can set environment variables specific to your environment that you can use to determine whether code should run on the worker or the web server. Here is a brief outline of the steps you could use:

1. Create a new application.
2. Create a web server environment within the application (for example "production").
3. Create a worker environment within the application (for example "production-worker").
4. Set an environment variable, for example `APP_ENVIRONMENT` (this name could be anything you choose) on production with the value "production", and with the value "production-worker" on the production-worker environment.
5. Create configuration files in `.ebextensions` to start/stop sidekiq (and any other programs needed for the worker) depending on if the `APP_ENVIRONMENT` variable name matches "worker".
6. Set up a `cron.yaml` file for background jobs (see [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html)).
7. For the background jobs, I create a separate cron controller for the endpoints listed in the `cron.yaml` file.
8. Deploy your code base to both the web server and worker environments. Subsequent changes can be deployed as needed to the appropriate environment.

For Sidekiq, your web application and your worker both need to be given access to the Redis server, so your application can create jobs and then the worker can pick them up to process.

Comment: Hi @haris-krajina , Were you able to setup above architecture for your Rails app on AWS. If yes, how did you achieve it? I have same requirements but with Resque.